# passing html tag in php variable

Tags: php, html

i want to pass anchor tag in php variable while values in href attribute are coming from another vairable. Code is shown below.

```
  echo "<a href='mailto:umair.malik@purelogics.net?Subject=Requesting measurement file for the following parameters&body=Backplane Connector = '".htmlspecialchars($aRow[$aColumns[0]])."' >Click here to request</a>";
```

problem is after this code is executed nothing appers in $aRow[$aColumns[0]] and code in firebug look like this below:
Click here to request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `'` befor concatenating the variable.Try with -

```
".htmlspecialchars($aRow[$aColumns[0]])."'
```

Instead of -

```
'".htmlspecialchars($aRow[$aColumns[0]])."'
```

Comment: accepted answer but i can't vote for you as it require 15 reputaqtion which i don't have now :) sorry